# How to declare a variable to be accessed by two functions in C?

Tags: global-variables

I have this boolean variable that need to be accessed by two functions. In C programming, instead of declaring as global variable, is there any other way?

Comment: What's wrong with the global variable?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. This is what global variables are for.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the value as a parameter if you only need your two functions to read the variable.

If you also need to change the variable from within the function, you will need to either use a global variable, or to send a pointer to the variable (which could be declared locally in whatever function ends up calling these other functions).